# Relationship one to many in EF

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-5.0

I have the following problem: it turns out that when I write the controller of my article table from my database, I get an error on my web page. I'm using ASP.NET Core 5 with a pre-existing database. I'm a newbie at this, I'm learning by creating projects.

In my controller class I have this:
https://codeshare.io/3AoPBB

I have this class `articlesviewmodel`:
https://codeshare.io/mp08vk

And this is my `articlemap`:
https://codeshare.io/0gQqZv

`DbContextSytem`: https://codeshare.io/1YD6Bj

`Article` table in SQL Server database:
https://codeshare.io/DZrPJk

Class `Category` for a table in SQL Server:

```
public class Category
{
    public int idcategory { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "The Category must not have more than 50 characters")]
    public string namecategory { get; set; }
    public string descategory { get; set; }
    public bool numberstatate { get; set; }

    // modify table category
    public ICollection<Article> articles { get; set; }
}
```

I really don't know what I can be doing wrong in the include

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it in the following way, it turns out that I got an error because the foreign key was missing between the category and articles tables, I solved it with the following line of code in the dbcontextsystem under `modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ArticleMap());`

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Article>().HasOne(a => a.Category).WithMany(c => c.articles).HasForeignKey(a => a.idcategory);
```